# Android SQL Query not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a query on my app

```
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM " + getName() + " WHERE " + FIRST_NAME + " LIKE '%" + fname + "%' OR " + LAST_NAME + " LIKE '%" + lname + "%' OR "
                + AREA_PRAC + " LIKE '%" + location + "%' AND " + REGION + " = '" + region + "'";
```

Sample Query:

```
SELECT * FROM view_member_list WHERE l_name LIKE "%Mend%" AND region  = "Region V"
```

In SqliteManager it shows the data with "%Mend%" on f_name or l_name or location AND with "Region V". But when i used it on my app. The result is different. It seems that it bypass the second condition:

```
"AND region = 'Region V' "
```

Comment: Maybe region comparison is case sensitivie?

Comment: I have a spinner for Region to control the value. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Show us the complete statement which is executed in your app.

Comment: Check the value coming from the region spinner. The query looks okay. I've a suggestion to user brackets more in a SQL query.

Comment: This is my full query: SELECT * FROM view_member_list WHERE f_name LIKE "%Mend%" OR l_name LIKE "%Mend%" OR area_prac LIKE "%Mend%" AND region='Region V'